# Not show popover when input isn't empty after hiding it once

Tags: javascript

I am doing input validation with Jquery and I'm showing popover if field is empty on blur , when field left empty then popover show and user enter data then popover hide,if he focused on input again even if it isn't empty popover show

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="UsernameLogin" 
  data-toggle="popover" data-content="Username is missed" data- 
  placement="bottom">
  $("#UsernameLogin").blur(function () {
      if($("#UsernameLogin").val() == "" ){
          $("#UsernameLogin").popover('show');
      }else{
          $("#UsernameLogin").popover('hide');
      }
  });
```

I expect it to not show popover when input isn't empty after hiding it once

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log($("#UsernameLogin").val() == "")` statement to see if its true or not?

Comment: Also `"" == ""` is `true` and `null == ""` is false. So might want to change it to `!$("#UsernameLogin").val()`